# How do you make a background Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make an array of images so that my full page background can switch between the images in m y array I have the Id on my html tag the image is being applied via CSS and I want the image to cycle through my array of images.

The code I have so far. Right my code change my whole page to the string of the location of the files for the images I want the background image to change not have my whole page turn white with some text at the top.

any help would be great.

```js
var backgroundArray = ["../images/video.jpg", "../images/stars2.jpg", "../images/junkyard.jpg"];
var bgIndex = 0;

function changeBackground(){
 var newBg = backgroundArray[bgIndex];
 var mainBg = document.getElementById('html');
 mainBg.innerHTML = newBg;
 bgIndex++;
 if (bgIndex > backgroundArray.length-1){
 bgIndex = 0;
 } 
}
```

```css
html
 background: url(../images/video.jpg) no-repeat 0 top fixed;
 background-size: cover;
```

```html
doctype
html(lang="en" id="html")
 head
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `innerHTML` which does replace the content of the page. If you want to change the background, use the `style` object on the element:

```
mainBg.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + newBg + ')';
```

You are basically creating a CSS rule, just as you would in a stylesheet, but building it in the string instead.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it helped you, which will make it easier for others to find it if they have a similar issue in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Of course I will accept the answer, do you mind clarifying why you have to use the('+ neweBg +') the "+ +" what do the +'s do exactly?

Comment: To set the style, you ultimately need a string. Something like `mainBg.style.backgroundImage = "url(../images/stars2.jpg)";`. But of course in your case you need that string to be built dynamically with the new image URL. So what we are doing is saying start with "url(", then add whatever the value of newBg is, then add the final ")" so we have a complete style.

Comment: @GentryRolofson In JavaScript the [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) operator is used both for addition and string concatenation depending on the context. If one of the operands is a string the other operand will be cast to a string and the result of the operation will be a new string that concatenates the operands. This implicit type conversion can cause unexpected results when you expect both operands to be numbers but one isn't: `"1" + 1` returns a string `"11"`, not the number `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + newBg + "')"
```

instead of

```
var mainBg = document.getElementById('html');
    mainBg.innerHTML = newBg;
```